# Cumulocity Java SDK API to post multiple measurements to Server

Tags: java, cumulocity

I am using Cumulocity Java Agent to send sensor's data from Agent to server.
Because of the volume of data is very huge, I want to send bulk of data in one Http post request.
But after spending some hours looking at the source code of package `com.cumulocity.sdk.client.measurement` I think there is only the version of posting only one measurement at once. Am I right ?
So, in my project, I am using HttpClient to send bulk of data (in format of a JSONArray) and it is working.
But my client wants to know why I have to implement it myself, so I wonder whether the API has not been implemented yet or I am wrong.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that the `com.cumulocity.sdk.client.measurement` does not offer an implementation for the bulk API for measurements at the moment.

However you can use the generic class `com.cumulocity.sdk.client.RestConnector` which is the base class for all the API implementations. It has a method `public <T extends ResourceRepresentationWithId> T post(String path, CumulocityMediaType mediaType, T representation) throws SDKException`. You can either manuallly call that method or you add a new class for MeasurementBulk API which implements it.

So you don't have to do this call completly outside of the library.

Comment: Thank you for you respond.
But now I have another question, I found that there are times my HTTP Request failed frequently. When I post an JSONArray of about 15.000 entities of measurement, the response is very slow and finally it failed. (Because I am using httpclient and will retry for 3 times when a request failed). Is there a limit of how many entities I can post in a http request ?

Comment: There is direct limitation. Maybe the client times out wihle the 15k measurements are created